# Initializer function c++

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to write a function that initializes a given string into a multidimensional array words[word][size]. My code outputs a rather strange result, and I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. The space character ' ' acts as a delimiter in my test case, and I'm supposed to make it such that each word occupies one row. My code is:

```
void initialize(char words[][MAX_WORD_SIZE], const char str[], char delimiter)
{
    for(int i = 0, k = 0; i < MAX_WORD; i++)
    {
        if(str[k] != delimiter)
        {
            strcpy(words[i], &str[k]);
        }
    }
    cout << *words;
 }
```

Here, const int MAX_WORD = 20, const int MAX_WORD_SIZE = 25, and this is my output:

```
we are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are     working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on     prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on prwe are working on project 3 of course CS31 and we will finish it soon
```

I dont understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What output you actually want? I've done a little work for you but I want to know this question first.

Comment: I want a word in each element of the array. So then I'll have:
words[1] = We
words[2] = are
words[3] = working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you forgot to increase k :

```
strcpy(words[i], &str[k++]);
```

Comment: With the following code:

http://imgur.com/gHgk8Fq

I get something like:

http://imgur.com/cRlccI7,

When I want:

We

are

working

on

and so on...

Comment: Well, if you take a look carefully, "we are working on pr" is exactly 20 characters. Maybe you are missing http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok too ?

Answer (score 0):

IMO your code is not safe!!!

each time you copy all the content of the input string into a fixed size memory; you easily do invalid write

Comment: I'm very new to programming. I'm not sure what exactly you mean by an invalid write?

Comment: An **invalid Write** happens where you write data in memory address out of your control. If your string is longer than MAX_WORD * MAX_WORD_SIZE characters, you write out of the _words_ capacity